# Python XML Parsing a String

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse in Python a XML string. For example:

```
   <policy-maps>
    <policy-map>
     <type>qos</type>
     <name>PROFILE1</name>
     <policy-map-rule>
      <class-name>voice</class-name>
      <class-type>qos</class-type>
      <priority-level>1</priority-level>
      <police>
       <rate>
        <value>30</value>
        <units>percent</units>
       </rate>
      </police>
      <queue-limit>
       <value>17</value>
       <unit>kbytes</unit>
      </queue-limit>
     </policy-map-rule>
     <policy-map-rule>
      <class-name>video</class-name>
      <class-type>qos</class-type>
      <police>
       <rate>
        <value>10</value>
        <units>percent</units>
       </rate>
       <burst>
        <value>5000</value>
        <units>bytes</units>
       </burst>
      </police>
     </policy-map-rule>
    </policy-map>
   </policy-maps>
```

I want to extract all the content in the tag "policy-map", or in the tag "police" inside a certain "policy-map" and "class-name". I've tried every example I could find, but no example seems to be exactly what I want to do, or work. Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the [XML package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html) in Python?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and we might be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat ... but since your data doesn't use attributes, converting to a dict might be easiest for you. (You might also like the [untangle](https://github.com/stchris/untangle) package.)

Note in the example below, I've used [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) to convert the xml to a nested ordered-dict, then you can use standard dictionary approaches to the results.

```
import xmltodict
import pprint

xml = """
   .... YOUR XML GOES HERE
"""

doc = xmltodict.parse(xml)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)
pp.pprint(doc['policy-maps']['policy-map']['policy-map-rule'])
```

yields;

```
[OrderedDict([('class-name', 'voice'),
              ('class-type', 'qos'),
              ('priority-level', '1'),
              ('police',
               OrderedDict([(...)])),
              ('queue-limit',
               OrderedDict([('value', '17'), ('unit', 'kbytes')]))]),
 OrderedDict([('class-name', 'video'),
              ('class-type', 'qos'),
              ('police',
               OrderedDict([(...), (...)]))])]
```